# How to add a label to a scatter, with multiple variables?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have created a scatter plot that has dots that vary with certain sizes of planets inside my table.
To achieve that, i used this function:

```
#data:
x=composition
y=composition
z=planetary_radii

#some stuff to let the scatter organized:
left, width = 0.1, 0.7
bottom, height = 0.1, 0.7
rect_scatter = [left, bottom, width, height]
ax_scatter = plt.axes(rect_scatter)

#the function that separates the dots in different colors:
colors = []
for i in z:
  if i > 8:
    colors.append('r')
  elif i<8 and i>4:
    colors.append('b')
  elif i<4 and i>2:
    colors.append('g')
  elif i<2:
    colors.append('orange')
  else:
    colors.append('y')

# the scatter plot:
ax_scatter.scatter(x, y,c=colors, s=10)
```

And after that, I want these dots to be in a label, but with names different than 'g', 'orange', etc. They would be like 'Radii>8','4

How can I achieve that? Do I have to create another function to use the label parameter inside db.scatter?

This image shows the scatter without label:

[image: example of scatter plot]

Comment: Split your data into lists. Then plot the lists individually `plt.plot( a, ..., label = 'a')` (advantage you pick the colors) or if you have many in a loop `plt.plot( aa[i], ..., label = label[i])` where label[i] is the list of labels. (Colors would be automatic or you could use a list of colors to be assigned in the loop). Then add a line `plt.legend()`

Comment: The newest matplotlib version (3.1) is able to do this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#automatedlegendcreation

Comment: @Solvalou I've tried using this function :
`legend1 = ax_scatter.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(), loc="lower right", title="Classes")
ax_scatter.add_artist(legend1)`
but I get the folowing error message: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'legend_elements'. How to counter that?

Comment: This is probably because you have an old version of `matplotlib`, as this is only supported in the newest one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got one solution utilizing the newest version of `matplotlib` which is 3.1.2. To install it, execute

```
pip install -U matplotlib
```

but please notice that it only works with Python3, since Python2 only supports `matplotlib` till version 2.

---

See the complete code here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

x=composition
y=composition
z=planetary_radii

# some stuff to let the scatter organized:
left, width = 0.1, 0.7
bottom, height = 0.1, 0.7
rect_scatter = [left, bottom, width, height]
ax_scatter = plt.axes(rect_scatter)

# the function that separates the dots in different classes:
classes = np.zeros( len(x) )    # z > 8
classes[(z <= 8) & (z > 4)] = 1
classes[(z <= 4) & (z > 2)] = 2
classes[z <= 2] = 3

# create color map:
colors = ['r', 'b', 'g', 'orange', 'y']
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom', colors, N=len(colors))

# the scatter plot:
scatter = ax_scatter.scatter(x, y, c=classes, s=10, cmap=cm)
lines, labels = scatter.legend_elements()

# legend with custom labels
labels = [r'Radii $> 8$', r'$4 <$ Radii $\leq 8$', 
          r'$2 <$ Radii $\leq 4$', r'Radii $\leq 2$']
legend = ax_scatter.legend(lines, labels,
                    loc="lower right", title="Classes")
ax_scatter.add_artist(legend)
plt.show()
```

Four classes are defined which depend on the value of `z`. Please note, that I changed the ranges a bit by using the less equals, since you excluded some values (like 4 and 8). Afterwards, a custom color map is defined in which the colors to the corresponding classes are set. The result is provided to the scatter plot, from which `lines` and `labels` are yielded by calling `legend_elements()`. You can now change these labels however you want and finally provide them to `ax_scatter.legend()`. Here you can also specify the title of the legend.

Comment: Well, this worked fine, thank you! One more question: in this new 'classes' method you used to separate the values of z, how can I also add the values that are different from numbers? (In my table I have some NaN values that need to be counted in the scatter as well)

Comment: You're welcome. You can filter NaNs by using `np.isnan(z)`. But what do you want to do with these? Since they are no numbers, you cannot plot them of course. Do you want to count them? Then you could simply do `len(np.isnan(z))` or similar. Also note that you get all numbers which are not NaN via `~np.isnan(z)`.

Comment: Actually, they just don't have numbers in the z column. So, they are placed in the scatter, but should be displayed with a different color than the others with real z values. I noticed they are displayed as red (just as z>8) in this scatter function you suggested. Maybe I can create another class for z>8 and let the 'np.zeros( len(x) )' be the NaN values?

Comment: I see. What you said should work. You could also try `classes[np.isnan(z)] = 4`. They should get assigned the color yellow then.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which also works in Python2.7, based on the comment of roadrunner66 is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.asarray(composition)
y = np.asarray(composition)
z = np.asarray(planetary_radii)

# some stuff to let the scatter organized:
left, width = 0.1, 0.7
bottom, height = 0.1, 0.7
rect_scatter = [left, bottom, width, height]
ax_scatter = plt.axes(rect_scatter)

# definition of filters, colors, and labels
filters = [z > 8, (z <= 8) & (z > 4), (z <= 4) & (z > 2), z <= 2]
colors = ['r', 'b', 'g', 'orange', 'y']
labels = ['Radii $> 8$', r'$4 <$ Radii $\leq 8$', 
        r'$2 <$ Radii $\leq 4$', r'Radii $\leq 2$']

# filter the data and plot:
for idx, f in enumerate(filters):
    ax_scatter.scatter(x[f], y[f], 
        c=colors[idx], s=10, label=labels[idx])

ax_scatter.legend(title='Classes', loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

First ensure that your data is stored in `np.array`s. `filters`, `colors` and `labels` can be set however you wish. Afterwards, the data is filtered using the previously defined filter criteria and plotted. Here, the specified `colors` and `labels` are applied.